# Trying to access a sets of variable from string (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, variables, switch-statement, pass-by-reference

Given this :

```
System.out.println("Make a choice : (1), (2), (3)");
//validation is a scanner already declare elsewhere
n = validation.nextLine();          
switch (n) {
    case "1":
        play(1);
        break;
    case "2":
        play(2);
        break;
    case "3":
        play(3);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("invalid");

/?? means I don't know
public static void play(1??){
System.out.print("Did you win? ( (y)es or (n)o ) ");
choice = validation.nextLine();
// if yes ?? ++win1
// if no ?? ++loose1
// I know how to do those loops, I don't know how to make the variable  choice fit the current case (++win2 and ++loose2 ans the case 2: for example)
}
```

My problem, for every cases, there are a set of specific variables that has to be increment (example `casevar1`, `win1`, `loose1`, etc.), if the case `2` is selected, I want that the variables in the `play()` method now automatically refer to the proper variables (example `casevar2`, `win2`, `loose2`, etc.). So how do I pass that information to the `play()` method?

Comment: Maybe wrap up the parameters into their own class, and put some objects of that class into an array?

Comment: For the simplest way, since you are passing 1,2,3 in play method, you could simple check what parameter is received and based on that use the set of appropriate variables. Not the best of decorated ways to do but this would fulfill the requirement.

Comment: David Wallace : any links that could help me on that? Not an expert at all, don't know how to create and manipulates classes, arrays and well... I'm new to programming. I know that I must know to do those things, I had only a small experience in visual basic, which mean, I know nothing... :( What would you suggest as a resource?

Comment: The Java tutorials published by Oracle are awfully good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. I think part of it is how to pass parameters to a method. Please follow the code and comments :

```
    //I used 3 integers just for demonstration purpose 
    int casevar1, win1, loose1,casevar2, win2, loose2;
    public static void main(String[]arghs){

        System.out.println("Make a choice : (1), (2), (3)");
        //validation is a scanner already declare elsewhere
        n = validation.nextLine();

        switch (n) {
            case "1":
                //assign values 
                casevar1 =7;  win1 =9; loose1 =0;
                play(casevar1, win1, loose1); //pass appropriate variables to play method
                break;
            case "2":
                //assign values 
                casevar2 =17;  win2 =8; loose2 = 4;
                play(casevar2, win2, loose2); //pass appropriate variables to play method
                break;
            case "3":
               //do like case "1" / case "2" 
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid");
        }//end of switch
    }

    //an example of a play method recieving 3 integers. 
    public static void play(int casevar, int win, int loose){

        System.out.print("Did you win? ( (y)es or (n)o ) ");
        choice = validation.nextLine();
        //follow Aku Nour's answer
    }
```

**EDITED**: Added an example to answer your question.
Create an object warping the data, as  @David Wallace suggested:

```
public class Test  {

    public static void main(String[]arghs){

        public static void main(String[]arghs){

            System.out.println("Make a choice : (1), (2), (3)");
            //validation is a scanner already declare elsewhere
            n = validation.nextLine();

            switch (n) {
            case "1":
                //set an object initialized to casevar =7, win =9, loose = 0
                play(new DataObject(7,9, 0)); 
                break;
            case "2":
                play(new DataObject(17,8, 4)); 
                break;
            case "3":
                //do like case "1" / case "2" 
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid");
            }//end of switch
        }

        //an example of a play method recieving 3 integers. 
        public static void play(){

            System.out.print("Did you win? ( (y)es or (n)o ) ");
            choice = validation.nextLine();
            //follow Aku Nour's answer
        }
    }


    //play method receiving data object 
    public static void play(DataObject data){

        System.out.print("Did you win? ( (y)es or (n)o ) ");
        choice = validation.nextLine();

        //
        casevar++;
    }

    //as  David Wallace proposed 
    //an object containing the 3 parameters you mentioned 
    class DataObject {


        private int casevar; private int win; private int loose;

        DataObject(int casevar, int win, int loose){

            this.casevar = casevar;
            this.win = win; 
            this.loose = loose;
        }

        public int getCasevar() {
            return casevar;
        }

        public void setCasevar(int casevar) {
            this.casevar = casevar;
        }

        public int getWin() {
            return win;
        }

        public void setWin(int win) {
            this.win = win;
        }

        public int getLoose() {
            return loose;
        }

        public void setLoose(int loose) {
            this.loose = loose;
        }
    }

}
```

If it doesn't answer or not clear enough don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What is in your first example is closer to what I want to do... but for instance, if I want that in the play function, I could do something like :
++casevar and that this would increment the proper casevar1 or casevar2 or casevar3 depending of the swich scenario, how I do that? Because this way, it's passing the value of the variable, but it seems only one way... do you get what i mean?
Sorry if I'm not clear enough, it's my first time here, I will try to express myselft better next time, thank you!

Comment: For instance, in your exemple if the case 1 is selected and i'm doing
++casevar in the play method, the result would be casevar1=8, which is correct, but if i'm choosing the case 1 again, the result is still 8 where it's suppose to be 9. Hope it's clearer that way.

Comment: In this case you can crate an object to hold the data as @ David Wallace suggested. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do somthing like this

```
public static void play(String s){

    System.out.print("Did you win? ( (y)es or (n)o ) ");
    choice = validation.nextLine();

    if("1".equals(s)) {
        if("y".equals(choice)) {
            win1 ++;
        } else if ("n".equals(choice)) {
            loose1 ++;
        }
    }

    if("2".equals(s)) {
        if("y".equals(choice)) {
            win2 ++;
        } else if ("n".equals(choice)) {
            loose2 ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ho, I get you on that, it's interesting, I'll try something of that type and i'll come back to you. But I was hoping to be able to do that in one batch if you get what I mean. If I could do a single loop that would handle the 3 cases... (it's my second week of JAVA, so anything help anyway, so thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with inspiration from you guys, I've answered my question. I did it this way :

in the main, something like that

```
case "1":
    play(1, nbEasy, easyPos, easyNeg);
    break;
case "2":
    play(2, nbInter, interPos, interNeg);
    break;
case "3":
    //same thing with hard
```

and in the play() method, something like that :

```
public static void play(int niv, int nbGames, int nbPos, int nbNeg){
    ++nbGames;
    System.out.print("Completed? ( (y)yes or (n)o ) ");
    choice = validation.nextLine();
    if (choice.equals("y")){
        ++nbPos;    
    }
    else if (choice.equals("n"))
        ++nbNeg;

    switch (niv){
        case 1:
            nbEasy=nbGames; easyPos=nbPos; easyNeg=nbNeg;
        case 2:
            nbInter=nbGames; interPos=nbPos; interNeg=nbNeg;
        case 3:
            //same thing with hard
    }
}
```

It’s perfect for me, because I can add a lot of lines in the first section of the play () method, working with what has been passed with the switch in the main and at the end, I’m affecting the new values to the proper variables.

I would like to thank you all, I’m new to programming and new to this community, but for having tried a bunch of places, that place looks by far the best. You’re responsive, polite, cordial, and I will read all the rules to suit better this place, prepare more my questions and when I will be able, I will help others. This place is amazing, I love you guys.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Up voted to encourage you ask, help, and get help.